# Combine multiple csv files

Tags: python, sql, csv, pandas

I am using [`q`](https://github.com/harelba/q) to transform my csv file: [log.csv](http://pastebin.com/FNisChiV) (file linked).
It's format is:

```
datapath,port,rxpkts,rxbytes,rxerror,txpkts,txbytes,txerror
4,1,178,25159,0,40,3148,0
4,2,3,230,0,213,27897,0
4,3,3,230,0,212,27807,0
4,4,4,320,0,211,27717,0
4,5,3,230,0,212,27807,0
4,6,3,230,0,212,27807,0
4,7,4,320,0,211,27717,0
4,8,4,320,0,211,27717,0
4,9,4,320,0,211,27717,0
4,a,4,320,0,211,27717,0
4,b,3,230,0,212,27807,0
4,fffffffe,7,578,0,209,27549,0
3,1,197,26863,0,21,1638,0
3,2,3,230,0,215,28271,0
3,3,5,390,0,215,28271,0
3,4,2,140,0,216,28361,0
3,5,4,320,0,214,28181,0
3,6,3,230,0,215,28271,0
3,fffffffe,7,578,0,212,28013,0
5,1,208,27401,0,6,488,0
5,fffffffe,7,578,0,208,27401,0
2,1,180,24228,0,18,1368,0
2,2,2,140,0,195,25366,0
2,3,2,140,0,195,25366,0
2,4,3,230,0,194,25276,0
2,5,3,230,0,194,25276,0
2,6,2,140,0,195,25366,0
2,fffffffe,7,578,0,191,25018,0
1,1,38,5096,0,182,23602,0
1,2,42,5419,0,179,23369,0
1,3,61,7152,0,159,21546,0
1,4,28,4611,0,192,24087,0
1,5,46,6022,0,174,22676,0
1,fffffffe,7,578,0,214,28210,0
```

I want to covert it into this format:
[image]

The number of ports can vary.

Current code:

```
python q -H -d "," "select rxpkts, txpkts from ./log.csv where datapath = i and port = j" > i_j.csv;
```

So I made `i*j` number of files and then combined them manually. Is there a way to do this in one go by modifying the above **sql query** or **combine files using python** or using **pandas** as suggested in comments?

```
import subprocess

def printit():
    for i in range(1,6):
        for j in range(1,6):
            query = "select rxpkts, txpkts from ./log.csv where datapath = "+str(i)+" and port = "+str(j)
            fileName = str(i)+"_"+str(j)+".csv"
            with open(fileName, "w+") as f:
                p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "q", "-H", "-d", ",", query], stdout=f)

printit()
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Comment: Please help with an example

Comment: In the link above, look at `In[3]/Out[3]` and you will see that it would convert data where the port is in the row to data where the port is in the column, except it does this with a column called "variable" instead of "port" and there is 1 value reorganized instead of 2.  I don't see a quick exact fit to your problem, which may require ignoring/eliminating some columns before using `pivot`.  To play with it, it may be helpful to start with `import pandas as pd` (if that doesn't work, install it with your package manager or perhaps `pip install pandas`) and `df = pd.read_csv(filename)`

Comment: yes I need only `datapath`, `port`, `rxpackets`, `txpackets`, rest can be dropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_index` together with `stack`.

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ======================================
print(df)

    datapath      port  rxpkts   ...     txpkts  txbytes  txerror
0          4         1     178   ...         40     3148        0
1          4         2       3   ...        213    27897        0
2          4         3       3   ...        212    27807        0
3          4         4       4   ...        211    27717        0
4          4         5       3   ...        212    27807        0
5          4         6       3   ...        212    27807        0
6          4         7       4   ...        211    27717        0
7          4         8       4   ...        211    27717        0
8          4         9       4   ...        211    27717        0
9          4         a       4   ...        211    27717        0
..       ...       ...     ...   ...        ...      ...      ...
24         2         4       3   ...        194    25276        0
25         2         5       3   ...        194    25276        0
26         2         6       2   ...        195    25366        0
27         2  fffffffe       7   ...        191    25018        0
28         1         1      38   ...        182    23602        0
29         1         2      42   ...        179    23369        0
30         1         3      61   ...        159    21546        0
31         1         4      28   ...        192    24087        0
32         1         5      46   ...        174    22676        0
33         1  fffffffe       7   ...        214    28210        0

[34 rows x 8 columns]


# reshaping
# ======================================
series_res = df[df.columns[:4]].set_index(['datapath', 'port']).stack()
series_res.name = 'value'



datapath  port             
4         1         rxpkts       178
                    rxbytes    25159
          2         rxpkts         3
                    rxbytes      230
          3         rxpkts         3
                    rxbytes      230
          4         rxpkts         4
                    rxbytes      320
          5         rxpkts         3
                    rxbytes      230
                               ...  
1         2         rxpkts        42
                    rxbytes     5419
          3         rxpkts        61
                    rxbytes     7152
          4         rxpkts        28
                    rxbytes     4611
          5         rxpkts        46
                    rxbytes     6022
          fffffffe  rxpkts         7
                    rxbytes      578
Name: value, dtype: int64



df_res = pd.DataFrame(series_res)
df_res.T

datapath      4                                         ...        1                                        
port          1              2              3           ...        4              5         fffffffe        
         rxpkts rxbytes rxpkts rxbytes rxpkts rxbytes   ...   rxpkts rxbytes rxpkts rxbytes   rxpkts rxbytes
value       178   25159      3     230      3     230   ...       28    4611     46    6022        7     578

[1 rows x 68 columns]
```